# Select tag is not working for Android chrome in Ionic Framework

Tags: angular, select, ionic-framework, ionic2, dropdown

I am using Ionic 2.2.xx. I used Select tag. It is not working in android devices(chrome browser); but in Ios (safari browser) and on desktop it's working fine. I tried out many of solutions. Anyone, please suggest the changes in my code...

```html
<div class = "item item-input"  style="border-radius: 5px;" data-ng-if="m1.InputControls == 'DropDownList'">
  <select class="item item-input" style="border-color: transparent;" name="{{m1.ColumnHeader}}">
    <option selected>--Select--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="p1 in m1.DropDownValues" value="{{p1.Value}}" >
      {{p1.Text}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `ng-options`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. All values are coming fine. but the drop down (select input type) is not expanding on clicking  in android chrome browser.

Comment: Seeing this same issue.